# Gesture detector onTap is not triggered

Tags: flutter

```
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("new screen"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 210,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Stack(
                  children: [
                    GestureDetector(
                        behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.pop(context);
                        },
                        child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
                    Center(
                      child: Text(
                        'set Destination',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 18,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Pickup Location',
                              fillColor: Colors.grey,
                              filled: true,
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              isDense: true,
                              contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    )
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: 10,
                ),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.grey,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8)),
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(2),
                        child: TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: 'Where to',
                              fillColor: Colors.grey,
                              filled: true,
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              isDense: true,
                              contentPadding:
                                  EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, top: 8, bottom: 8)),
                        ),
                      ),
                    )),
                    SizedBox(
                      width: 10,
                    )
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
```

Comment: is this your first screen in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not pushing any route on the Navigator stack, so you are trying to pop from an empty list (ie, there is nothing inside the stack to be popped).
Your gesture detector is working fine, i had tested it on dartpad but in your stack you have nothing to show after its pop.

Answer (score 0):

is the code below?

```html
Widget build(BuildContext context) { 
return MaterialApp( 
home: Scaffold( 
        appBar: AppBar( title: Text("new screen"), ), 
body: Column( 
    children: [ 
        Container( 
            height: 210, 
            decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white), 
            child: Column( 
                children: [ 
                    Stack( 
                        children: [ 
                        GestureDetector( behavior:      HitTestBehavior.translucent, 
                            onTap: () { Navigator.pop(context); },
```

try use this :
Navigator.of(context).pop();

Comment: I tried it but its not working

Comment: you need to tell the situation, if it displays on the initial page of course the pop navigator will not work because it needs the screen you have gone through, if so you can do a navigator push to the class/page you are going to

for reference
https://medium.com/flutter-community/flutter-push-pop-push-1bb718b13c31

Answer (score 0):

hello pragneshReddy & ibehavikmakwana There is nothing wrong with the code..

I have tested your code on Dartpad and it runs without error..
for Close your current screen try to use `Navigator.of(context).pop();`
and also.

**you should wrap your app with 2 different stateless widget for getting better approaches**

[image]

Comment: Tap is working but navigator.pop has no effect. I want to go back

Comment: no need for greetings in the answer